# Force all traffic through VPN Wndows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, vpn

I am using SoftEther VPN, I can connect to my server however I am unable to force traffic through the VPN. Is there a setting to control this in Windows or do I need to handle this at the application level?

Comment: This depends on the configuration of the VPN, but windows out of the box, if connected to a vpn will be connected to that network but your vpn can still leak your identity.

Comment: However if it is not connecting how do I find the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the Virtual Network adapter. I was not able to repair it but by deleting it and using Soft Ether Client Manager to create a new one it works.